# Stream a Webpack build to the browser

Tags: node.js, webpack

Just curious if there is a way to pipe/stream a Webpack build to the browser, something like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

app.use(function(req,res,next){ 
  webpack.build().pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: I see there is a gulp plugin that can probably do this:https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream

Comment: But I am wondering if there is a way to do this for the purposes of library code instead of application code.